# "No @implementation found for the class" error in Storyboard in Swift

Tags: swift, storyboard, iboutlet

I'm trying to create in IBOutlet in Swift using my Storyboard and assistant editor, but I'm receiving a strange error I've never seen before. Looks Objective-C-ish.

I navigated to my ViewController's Save button in my Storyboard

[image: storyboard list]

Then I control-click dragged the Save UIButton to Xcode's assistant editor to make the IBOutlet. I get the error "Could not insert new outlet connection: No @implementation found for the class "ClassBVC". How do I avoid this error so I can make the outlet and an action?

[image: IBOutlet error]

I noticed when I click the button with the four squares before "Manual" and the < > buttons, I can go to "Counterparts" and there's a "ClassBVC" file with the same name, but with "(Interface)" next to it. It's not the file that I need though. Even when trying to create an outlet there, I get the same error.

Comment: Did you try rebuilding your project?  Are there any compile errors in that file that might be making it so Xcode doesn't understand the class declaration for ClassBVC?

Comment: Tried rebuilding, cleaning, closing the project, reopening. No other errors.

Comment: After several restarts of my computer, it fixed itself somehow.

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem. rebuilding works for me.

Comment: None of the above worked. Only a reboot fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try closing Xcode and opening it again.

Comment: This worked for me sadly (for Apple's sake). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Creating one @IBOutlet directly in the view controller, and then creating the reference to the component in the Outlet Section in .storyboard worked for me. After that, I was able to drag the components normally to their respective view controller.